# Help with predicate logic translation

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, logic-translation

4. Translate into predicate form. 
   No one hates Bob. 
   [H = “is hate”]
   ∼∃x∀y H_b
5. Translate into predicate form. 
   Dogs are not reptiles. 
   [D = “is a dog”, R = “is a reptile”]
   ∀x(Dx⟶ ∼Rx)
6. Translate into predicate form. 
   Nothing is blue. 
   [B = “is blue”]
   ∼∃xBx or ∀x∼Bx
7. Translate into predicate form. 
   [C = “is cat”, M = “Mars”, A = “mammals”]
   No cat lives on Mars. Unless all cats are mammals, Bob, the cat, lives on Mars. Therefore, only mammals are cats. 
   ∀x(Cx⟶∼M), ∀x(∼Cx⟶Ax) ⟶(C B ⟶Mx) ⊢ Mx⟶∃xCx

What I need help is are these the correct predicate translations for these sentences so I need some feedback if they are translated correctly.

Comment: Someone Hates someone other. Thus Hate must be binary : $H(x,y)$. With it, 4) is  $\lnot ∃x H(x, B)$

Comment: "Dogs are not reptiles" is "there is no $x$ that is a Dog and a Reptile".

Comment: For 7), either M=Mars is a name, and thus you cannot negate it, or it is a predicate M(x) that transaltes "x lives on Mars".

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA "For all things, if it's a dog, then it's not a reptile," is *also* okay.

Answer (score 1):

> 4. Translate into predicate form. 
>      No one hates Bob. 
>      [H = “is hate”]
>      ∼∃x∀y H_b

You quantify an $x$ and a $y$ ... but don't use them in the actual formulae that is being quantified. So, the quantifiers end up doing nothing.

Also, what are the $x$ and $y$ supposed to be?  The $x$ could be the person (not) doing the hating of Bob .. but who or what is $y$?  .... The $y$ is unnecessary.

So ... what we need to say is 'there is not a $x$ such that $x$ hates Bob'

This translates as $\neg \exists x \ Hxb$

5. Translate into predicate form. 
   Dogs are not reptiles. 
   [D = “is a dog”, R = “is a reptile”]
   ∀x(Dx⟶ ∼Rx)

Good. You correctly surmised that this English statement is most likely meant to be about *all* dogs.

6. Translate into predicate form. 
   Nothing is blue. 
   [B = “is blue”]
   ∼∃xBx or ∀x∼Bx

Also good! Note that likewise for number 4. you could have done $\forall x \ \neg Hxb$

7. Translate into predicate form. 
   [C = “is cat”, M = “Mars”, A = “mammals”]
   No cat lives on Mars. Unless all cats are mammals, Bob, the cat, lives on Mars. Therefore, only mammals are cats. 
   ∀x(Cx⟶∼M), ∀x(∼Cx⟶Ax) ⟶(C B ⟶Mx) ⊢ Mx⟶∃xCx

First premise is: $\forall x (Cx \to \neg Mx)$  (you forgot the $x$ in $Mx$). But we can also ranslate this as $\neg \exists x (Cx \land Mx)$ ('there is no cat that lives on Mars')

Second premise: "Unless [P], [Q]$ translates to: 'If not [P}, then [Q]

Now, your [P] here is: all cats are mammals, which is $\forall x (Cx \to Ax)$

While the [Q] is: 'Bob is a cat and lives on Mars', which is $Cb \land Mb$

Putting these together, we thus get as the translation for premise 2:

$\neg \forall x (Cx \to Ax) \to (Cb \land Mb)$

Conclusion: 'only mammals are cats' This can be understood as: 'For anything: if it is a cat, then is is a mammal'. And so this translates as: $\forall x (Cx \to Ax)$.